# Is there a way to convert .ipynb or .py file to .do stata file?

Tags: python, stata

We ran some regression models in python `.py` and `.ipynb`, however, we'd like to do convert this to `.do` file for users who only use Stata.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean changing the extension, or translating the code from Stata to Python? If the first, both .py files and .do files are simple text files, so manually changing the extension will do it. You probably mean the latter though. To my knowledge there is no automated way to translate Python code to Stata code, you will need someone who knows both languages to translate it.

Comment: I forgot about Stata's Python integration, as thebadgateway mentioned. This would indeed mean that you can reuse much of the Python code but you need to make sure it will be picked up by Stata, so it still requires some manual changes.

Answer (score 1):

For the notebook file, this can be programmatically achieved with [`nbconvert`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), specifically by developing an [`Exporter`](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/exporters.html) that ports or closes the notebook source to Stata source. Alternatively, `nbconvert` has existing exporters that can convert a `ipynb` file to a `.py` file, whereby [PyStata maybe can be used](https://www.stata.com/features/overview/pystata-python-integration/).